# make sbt update resources in test

Tags: sbt, config, typesafe

I'm having trouble with resource loading during `sbt test`.

If I put a typesafe config file in my test resources directory, e.g. `src/test/resources/test.conf`, then when I run `test` it loads fine.  But if I edit `src/test/resources/test.conf` and run `test` again, I don't see the edits.  I have to exit sbt and start over to see the changes I made.  Doing `clean` and `test:clean` doesn't help.

I also tried doing

```
ConfigFactory.invalidateCaches()
ConfigFactory.load("test")
```

in my test code when I load the config, and tried adding `fork in test := true` to my build, but none of it makes any difference.

Any help's appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Having a heckuva time making a repro outside of the big project this is happening in, so it's something subtle that I'm probably not going to spend too much time on since there's a working workaround.